# Скачать файл c помощью pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Как скачать файл который прислали в личном сообщении с помощью pyrogram

Answer (score 0):

```
# Download from Message
app.download_media(message)

# Download from file id
app.download_media(message.photo.file_id)

# Keep track of the progress while downloading
def progress(current, total):
    print(f"{current * 100 / total:.1f}%")

app.download_media(message, progress=progress)
```

См. [Доки](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/download_media)